# I don't understand this parameter expansion: ${p//[0-9]/}

Tags: linux, shell, parameters, expansion

In Linux `/etc/init.d/functions` script I found the following parameter expansions that I don't quite understand:

```
${p//[0-9]/}  replace all instances of any number to/by what?

${1##[-+]}  This seems to remove all the longest left instances of minuses and pluses?

${LSB:-}  This seems to say that if LSB is not set then set nothing? in other words do nothing?
```

Comment: Tangentially related: The _source and purpose of the `$LSB` variable_ in the context of `/etc/init.d/functions` specifically (such as found on RHEL-like systems), is the subject of [this Unix & Linux SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/364021/54804).

Answer (score 4):

These are instances of `bash` **Shell Parameter Expansion**;
see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Note: `ksh` and `zsh` support the expansions in your question, too (I'm unclear on the full extent of the overlap in functionality), whereas `sh` (POSIX-features-only shells), does NOT support the string-replacement expansion, `${p//[0-9]/}`.

---

```
${p//[0-9]/}
```

**Removes all digits**: replaces all (`//`) instances of digits (`[0-9]`) with an empty string - i.e., it *removes* all digits (what comes after the last `/` is the replacement string, which is empty in this case).

```
${1##[-+]}
```

**Strips a single leading `-` or `+`, if present**: Technically, this removes the longest prefix (`##`) composed of a *single* `-` or `+` character from parameter `$1`. Given that the search pattern matches just a *single* character, there is no need to use `##` for the *longest* prefix here, and `#` - for the *shortest* prefix - would do.

```
${LSB:-}
```

**A no-op designed to prevent the script from breaking when run with the `-u` (`nounset`) shell attribute**: Technically, this expansion means: In case variable `$LSB` is either *not set or empty*, it is to be replaced with the string following `:-`, which, in this case, is also empty.

While this may seem pointless at first glance, it has its purpose, as [Sigi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3566933/sigi) points out:

"
The `${LSB:-}` construct makes perfect sense if the shell is invoked with the `-u` option (or `set -u` is used), and the variable `$LSB` might actually be unset. You then avoid the   shell bailing out if you reference `$LSB` as `${LSB:-}` instead. Since it's good practice to   use set `-u` in complex scripts, this move comes in handy quite often.
"

Comment: +1, *especially* for understanding and explaining what `${1##[-+]}` does since many people get this wrong and use this construct to e.g. strip all leading whitespace or zeroes which **does not work this way**.

Answer (score 0):

```
${p//[0-9]/} # removes digits from anywhere in `$p`

${1##[-+]} # removes + or - from start in $1

${LSB:-} # not really doing anything
```